How to run a command using command line arguments for Windows Terminal using wt command?
I'm trying to setup my environment. The below code is working, I just need to execute "Code ." in the new tab opened. Tried doing -Command 'code .' , -c 'code .'  , but no luck.
Here's my script.bat:
@echo off
set "backend=C:\Users\porfavor\inc-backend"

cd %backend%

wt --maximized -d "%backend%\services\api" -p "Git Bash" ; -d %backend% -p "Git Bash" --tabColor #088DA5 < I want to open vscode here >


I don't understand why you are trying to get wt to launch vscode for you.
Why not execute vscode on the next line?  If I am being dumb (very possible), please enlighten me.

Use bash -c code . instead of -c code . or even -Command code .
The following code snippet works for me (I use Ubuntu-24.04 profile not having the Git Bash one installed):
set "prof=Ubuntu-24.04"
wt --maximized -d "%backend%\services\api" -p "%prof%" ; -d "%backend%" -p "%prof%" --tabColor #088DA5 bash -c code .


FYI: Initially, I have debugged a similar issue for the Command Prompt profile as follows:
set "prof=Command Prompt"
wt --maximized -d "%backend%\services\api" -p "%prof%" ; -d "%backend%" -p "%prof%" --tabColor #088DA5 cmd /c code .

